# A question was deleted by its owner, but the  Points me to the faq because my answer was deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

A question was seemingly deleted by its owner. When I went to revisit [my *answer* to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758528/margin0-auto-doesnt-work-with-unordered-list/7758610#7758610), naturally it was deleted as well, and below it, I found the line: "Why was your post deleted? See the faq."

I didn't see that the question itself was deleted, so I read the faq, figuring I might have done something wrong.

Maybe it could just say. "Answer is deleted because the question is deleted" to prevent confusion. Or did I indeed do something wrong there?

Comment: Since it was delete at exactly the same second as the question it's clear that it was just deleted with the question. Still, a better message would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems sensible. Normally, you'd *notice* the question being deleted first, but following a direct link to it could obscure that fact... And the FAQ probably isn't relevant then.